# Push local submodule changes to repo without changing submodule's parent repo

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

How would I go about pushing changes that I made locally to a submodule to my own git repo without changing the content of the submodule's parent repo?  All the resources I found only mention pushing code to change the parent repo and then updating the submodule, however I do not have access to the parent repo.

Comment: "Changes to a repository" is, as a phrase, not *wrong* but not very precise either. Normally, what you do with a Git repository is *add new commits to the repository*. A submodule is a *separate Git repository* and adding commits to repository **R** never affects some other repository **S** at all. So there's nothing at all to do here.

Comment: If you have some superproject **S** that (among other things) says "take commit `C` from repository **R**", and you add new commits to **R**, what would you describe as having happened to superproject **S**?